# fatal error: H5Cpp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, hdf5

I am trying to compile an application with the HDF5 lib. I installed the lib via ubuntus 18.04 package manager. My CMakeLists looks like

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
   project(hdf)

   find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX)

   add_executable(hdf hdf.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(hdf ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
   set_property(TARGET hdf PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

   message(STATUS "INCLUDE LOCATION" ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   message(STATUS "version" ${HDF5_VERSION})
   message(STATUS "DEFINITIONS" ${HDF5_DEFINITIONS})
   message(STATUS "LIBRARIES" ${HDF5_LIBRARIES})
   message(STATUS "HL_LIBRARIES" ${HDF5_HL_LIBRARIES})
```

running cmake, the output yields

```
 HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine CXX configuration
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so (found version "1.10.0.1") found components:  C CXX 
-- INCLUDE LOCATION/usr/include/hdf5/serial
-- version1.10.0.1
-- DEFINITIONS-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
-- LIBRARIES/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_cpp.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
-- HL_LIBRARIES
```

so apparently the files are all found.

However, if I am not trying to compile a simple example and include the dependencies with

```
#include "H5Cpp.h"
```

I get

```
fatal error: H5Cpp.h: No such file or directory
 #include "H5Cpp.h"
```

why is that? Help is appreciated

Comment: Is the HDF5 headers installed in a standard location? It doesn't seem like that, perhaps they are installed in a sub-directory in a standard location? Or perhaps they're not installed in a standard location at all, in which case you need to use `HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS` as specified in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindHDF5.html). You can add the directory with e.g. [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions of cmake older than 3.19, the targets exposed by the ${HDF5_LIBRARIES} do not automatically set the include directories.

You need to explicitly set:

```
target_include_directories(hdf PRIVATE ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

As of cmake 3.19, `find_package(HDF5)` creates proper targets you can use for `target_link_libraries` which will automatically set the correct includes:

```
target_link_libraries(hdf PRIVATE hdf5::hdf5 hdf5::hdf5_cpp)
```

Compare https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindHDF5.html (current) to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/FindHDF5.html (last version before the proper targets were introducted).

A version that would support both new and old cmake would be:

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS C CXX)

if(TARGET hdf5::hdf5)
    # cmake >= 3.19
    target_link_libraries(hdf PRIVATE hdf5::hdf5 hdf5::hdf5_cpp)
else()
    # cmake < 3.19
    target_link_libraries(hdf PRIVATE ${HDF5_C_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(hdf PRIVATE ${HDF5_C_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${HDF5_CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS}
endif()
```

Comment: I just figured that out. I am so used to the :: syntax in the link libraries section which handles both, that I forgot about that, when linking libs the old way. thank you

Comment: Recent versions of cmake (cmake >= 3.19) export targets for the HDF5 libraries, so doing `target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC hdf5::hdf5)` "just works"