# How to link hdf5 c++ (MAC)

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, homebrew, hdf5

I'm pretty new to c++ and I'm trying to figure out how to link hdf5 with my Mac. I've `brew install hdf5`, however when I try to include the header file:
`#include "H5Cpp.h"` in my c++ code I get an error that says "No such file or directory".

How do I help c++ find the hdf5 installation?

Comment: Find out where H5Cpp.h is located and use its base path in the compiler flag `-I`. The better way is using cmake, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54570110/fatal-error-h5cpp-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Thanks so much @273K

Answer (score 1):

As @273K said (the header file from home-brew are located in `/usr/local/include/`:
so this works:

`g++ -I /usr/local/include main.cpp`

Where main.cpp has the line:

`#include "H5Cpp.h"`